# Using generics to return List of various types

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns

Trying to get my head around generics and am wanting to create a class that returns records of various types.

So what I want is something like this:

```
public class Job
{
    public JobType Type { get; set; }

    public Job (JobType jobType)
    {
        Type = jobType;
    }

    public IList<T> GetRecords<T>()
    {
       IList<T> records = new IList<T>();

       if (Type == JobType.Type1)
       {
           List<Type1Record> records = GetType1Records();
       }
       if (Type == JobType.Type2)
       {
            List<Type2Record> records = GetType2Records();
       }
        return records;
    }
}
```

I would want to call this using something like

```
var job = new Job(JobType.Type1);

var jobRecords = Job.GetRecords();
```

I think the code above conveys the intention but I am beginning to think that I am going about this in the wrong way because the above just doesn't work at all. IList cannot be converted to other types like this.

Does anybody know how I can achieve something like this.

Comment: Polymorphism. The function should return an `IEnumerable<SomeBaseTypeOrInterfaceAllYourJobsInherit>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the point of generics a bit. If you're trying to deal with multiple specific types in a generic method, that usually means you're going in the wrong direction.

One possible solution to your problem is to have your `Records` inherit from some shared base class:

```
public class Job
{
    public JobType Type { get; set; }

    public Job (JobType jobType)
    {
        Type = jobType;
    }

    // Type1Record and Type2Record both inherit from RecordBase
    public IEnumerable<RecordBase> GetRecords()
    {
       if (Type == JobType.Type1)
       {
           return GetType1Records();
       }
       if (Type == JobType.Type2)
       {
            return GetType2Records();
       }

       return null;
    }
}
```

Note that you need to return an `IEnumerable<T>` here, not an `IList<T>`, because doing the above with `IList<T>` would break covariance.

It looks like you might be better off using generics at the class level.

```
public abstract class Job<TRecord>
{
    public abstract IList<TRecord> GetRecords();
}

public class Type1Job : Job<Type1Record>
{
    public override IList<Type1Record> GetRecords()
    {
        // implementation
    }
}

public class Type2Job : Job<Type2Record>
{
    public override IList<Type2Record> GetRecords()
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```